# How to error check for a `null` object by the `json` interpreter in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnull

**update: I think the error is coming from a missing key in the data feed and not a key with a null value.**

I've been running into a `null` object by the `json` interpreter and thought this code would error check and avoid the crash. It's not working though. I need to check to avoid this error message and crash:

```
imageurl string is <null>
2013-09-09 12:35:26.928 1000 [1539:690b] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

if (![imageUrlString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{

    imageUrlString = [userImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


} else {

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest.png"];

}
```

fyi - it works if the image string exists and is only crashing when a null object is encountered.

the output from nslog:

when a null obj is encountered: `imageurl string is (null)`

when it works: `imageurl string is http://******.com/uploads/users/35/profile.jpeg`

thanks for help

Comment: imageurl string is  array or string?

Comment: imageurlstring is an NSString declared in the .h file. thanks!

Comment: if([imageUrlString isEqual: [NSNull null]])
NSLog(@"null"); try this

Comment: You test `imageUrlString` for `NSNull`, but then *replace* it by `[userImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` - that looks suspicious at least! - Which line produces the "imageurl string is <null>" output, and which line exactly crashes?

Comment: @MartinR the first part of the if statement causes the crash if a null obj is encountered    imageUrlString = [userImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; the output from nslog: like this imageurl string is (null) instead of imageurl string is http://******.com/uploads/users/35/profile.jpeg

Comment: @user2588945: You give incomplete or contradictory information. In your question, the output is "<null>", now it is "(null)". You should show the complete code with the NSLog statements and the corresponding output. Otherwise people can only *guess* about your problem.

Comment: @MartinR I think the error is coming from a missing key in the data feed and not a key with a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It don't think that your check for NSNull is not the proper technique to check for a null. Try one of the checks in the first `if` statement:

```
/* Either of these checks in the if statement should work */
if ((NSNull *)imageUrlString != [NSNull null] || [@"<null>" isEqualToString:imageUrlString]) {
    imageUrlString = [userImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest.png"];
}
```

Comment: `[NSNull null]` has no `isEqualToString:` method.